# Etiquette in letter writing: 'I am writing' vs 'I was writing'

Tags: grammar, tenses, email

I regularly write emails to colleagues and tend to start my letters with 'I was writing to ask if...'**.** Should I replace it with 'I **am** writing to ask if...'? 
I think so because I *am* writing at this time.

I know this may not be the best way to start emails, but nonetheless, which usage is grammatically accurate?

Comment: *I was writing..* is fine, because it precedes the if-clause, it's a super way to make a polite request. If (ha!) there is no "if-clause", then either verb tense is acceptable but I'd prefer the present tense. "I'm writing to enquire..." "I'm writing to inform you..."

Comment: @Mari-LouA, how does the presence/absence of the 'if-clause' make a difference?

Comment: In my opinion, the "if-clause" adds a more hesitant note. It's similar to the "I was wondering if you would-clause" when you want to make a polite request, you are aware that the listener might be busy with other things more important. "I was writing to ask if.." and "I was wondering if..." are a bit redundant but they help make an enquiry or request sound less like a order.

Comment: While writing the letter you would be **writing** in a present tense, **asking** in a present tense but would refer to having **wondered** (and therefore been prompted to write) in a past tense. You would write "**I am writing to ask...**", "**I was wondering...**" or, the slightly tortured "**I am writing because I was wondering...**".

Comment: While we're on the topic, does anyone have a problem with, "Dear Soandso, I write to ask if...?" This avoids the problem altogether.

Comment: @MikeC, could you make that an answer?

Comment: @user1993, I duplicated my comment as an answer as per your request :)

Comment: I agree with Mike. "I was writing" is really awkward because it reads as though you're reflecting on the past and reporting your act of composing the email. This is different from "I was wondering", in which case the act of wondering naturally precedes the act of writing the email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While writing the letter you would be **writing** in a present tense, **asking** in a present tense but would refer to having **wondered** (and therefore been prompted to write) in a past tense. You would write "**I am writing to ask**...", "**I was wondering**..." or, the slightly tortured "**I am writing because I was wondering**...".